# How to adjust the width of an existing GDI Pen?

Tags: graphics, gdi, pen

I am working on legacy code that relies on GDI (not GDI+) for drawing. GDI has no provision for variable width pens and you need to create/destroy new ones every time.

Is there any hack that allows to bypass that creation process and directly modify the width of an existing pen ?

Answer (score 0):

I did not find a way to alter a pen. So the solution I adopted is to keep a permanent pen of with 1 (most often used), and temporarily create a custom one when another width is requested. This at least allows me to mix two different widths without multiple creations/deletions.

Comment: Regarding your "permanent pen": You can use `GetStockObject` with `DC_PEN`. This is a special pen that implicitly exists once for each DC. The pen's color can be changed with `SetDCPenColor`, although its width cannot be changed.

Comment: @dialer: my question is about width, the DC_PEN does not help. This was a weird design decision of MS.

Comment: I read that. But the `DC_PEN` can still replace your "permanent pen". I never claimed that it can solve your original problem.

Comment: @dialer: right, that's what I did actually.